# How do I read the content of a file from the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the URL to a shared FileCloud in my database. I want to change it with content of a shared file.

How can I read the content from the URL?

I used this code to try but it doesn't read the content of the file

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(new System.Uri("https://filecloud.company.de/ui/core/index.html?mode=single&path=/SHARED/test/test.txt"), @"C:\MyProjects\test.txt");
            }
```

Comment: The question is a little hard to follow but I think you are looking for a way to open the file instead of saving it to local storage- in that case you might find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106960/convert-to-stream-from-a-url

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, i have the Solution for it . First i just had the url to the Website and not to file, that was the problem. Now i have the right url to download and it work finde with webClient

Comment: Thanks for the update, you can add the answer how did you resolve the problem.